# Ability to view SonicWall WAN bandwidth in real time?

Tags: bandwidth, sonicwall

We have a SuperMassive 9200 and a 100Mbit circuit, we have PRTG monitoring the connection and will error when it hits 90%, we have times where that happens and its 100% or higher. We have not found a good way of viewing the bandwidth breakdown in realtime to determine what is utilizing the connection. We also have GMS implemented with this device in it.

I have already looked through the various dashboards but these are not that useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the real time monitor and filter to match your desired interface to view how much bandwidth is using that interface, and which applications are using that bandwidth.

[image: Real-Time Monitor]

Also, you can use GMS in distributed mode and setup a [Flow Server](http://help.sonicwall.com/help/sw/eng/7634/8/0/0/content/Configuring_Flow_Activity.31.04.htm) to view this from the GMS itself.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion however I am trying to get a breakdown from everything on my side to identify what is using the traffic vs per interface.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, I would suggest Cacti or Grafana (Cloud). Cacti is very good in making network bandwidth diagrams and is open source. You do need some IaaS to be able to run it.